# Please suggest how to write a text from webpage text box to clipboard

Tags: python, cgi, clipboard

I have a text box in the webpage, a text in that text box i need that to be sent to the clipboard of ubuntu how do i do that? I'm using python CGI, Please suggest me a link or Idea to proceed.

Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry i'm just a beginner in python, when i saw the wxpython  documentation thought it would be helpful for this question, if i'm wrong please do correct me :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and cgi run on the server, but you want to copy text from the webpage that a client is viewing to the client's clipboard.

Hence you have to do your solution client-side with javascript or a javascript library like jQuery.  This used to be do-able using [jQuery clipboard](http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/), though this was a security problem as rogue flash apps could arbitrarily alter the users clipboard (causing people to paste the wrong URL, etc).  So, flash fixed the [security hole](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-10021715-83.html) that allowed client scripts to alter the clipboard whenever the script wanted, so up to date versions of flash can't alter the clipboard unless the user initiating the action with a click inside a flash movie.

However, http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/ still works (requiring you to click a button before it can modify the clipboard), so you can use that.  They have test pages and an [wiki of instructions](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions)

---

Getting text from the ubuntu (assuming GNOME as desktop environment) clipboard into a python script can be done with

```
import  pygtk
import gtk
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
print clipboard.wait_for_text()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will go with your suggestion:)  So this text that comes in the clipboard can be used by my running python application in my computer??

Comment: @Bhuvan:  Now I'm confused what you are doing.  My answer assumed you controlled the webpage and wanted to provide a clickable button, so a viewer of the webpage could copy the text in the webpage to the clipboard.

Comment: @jimbob, Sorry that was exactly what my question meant. Your answer is bang on :) I'm going through the procedure once i find it to be working i will accept the answer too :) I was actually curious about my next step after your fast reply, thought i would ask how to copy from clipboard to python application, I think i should make it as a different question. By the way sorry for confusing and troubling you :-/

Comment: @bhuvan: once its in the clipboard (of the active user), you can get it back into python with the above edit.  Granted it assumes GNOME (GTK), though other solutions exist.  This seems very inefficient way of doing things (generating a webpage via a python CGI server, reading the text from a client-side web browser, using javascript/flash to send text to the clipboard and back to a python script).  If you just need user input, why not have it be entered straight into python?  Or if you need a fully interactive website why not just use a python framework like django?

Comment: Oh django builds a webpage, i never knew this, So you suggest me to look at django than this lengthy process??

Comment: Django is a python based web framework -- it has plenty of documentation and tutorials.  Its handy for doing things like generating a dynamic web page (based on stored user data), accessing/storing information from the webpage in a database, letting users input data in html forms, and launching python scripts acting on and manipulating the stored data.  It just seems your solution is overly complicated and basically wants a user to input data in a web page and use that data in a python script, and doesn't need anything in the clipboard.  See http://www.djangoproject.com